# Convert or strip out "illegal" Unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode, pymssql

I've got a database in MSSQL that I'm porting to SQLite/Django. I'm using pymssql to connect to the database and save a text field to the local SQLite database.

However for some characters, it explodes. I get complaints like this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 1916: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there some way I can convert the chars to proper unicode versions? Or strip them out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you have the string of bytes `s`, instead of using it as a unicode obj directly, convert it explicitly with the right codec, e.g.:

```
u = s.decode('latin-1')
```

and use `u` instead of `s` in the code that follows this point (presumably the part that writes to sqlite).  That's assuming `latin-1` is the encoding that was used to make the byte string originally -- it's impossible for us to guess, so try to find out;-).

As a general rule, I suggest: don't process in your applications any text as encoded byte strings -- decode them to unicode objects right after input, and, if necessary, encode them back to byte strings right before output.

Comment: Indeed, you have to know what encoding your text is in. There's pretty much no way around this. In your case, fortunately, your error message makes it obvious. It's almost sure bet that you are dealing with Microsoft's annoying cp1252, due to the presence of a 0x97 character.  In latin-1, this codepoint holds a control character, "END OF GUARDED AREA" which is almost never used. You will never see this precise error with utf-8 as 0x97 is not a valid character-leading byte. In cp1252, on the other hand, it is the very common emdash.

Answer (score 11):

When you decode, just pass 'ignore' to strip those characters

there is some more way of stripping / converting those are

```
'replace': replace malformed data with a suitable replacement marker, such as '?' or '\ufffd' 

'ignore': ignore malformed data and continue without further notice 

'backslashreplace': replace with backslashed escape sequences (for encoding only)
```

Test

```
>>> "abcd\x97".decode("ascii")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
>>> "abcd\x97".decode("ascii","ignore")
u'abcd'
```

Comment: python throws errors even when 'ignore' is used. There seems to be no combination of decode/encode that I can get to strip out any useless UTF-8 characters that I couldn't give the slightest shit about.